# What column type to use for storing a `date` that may leave out month and day?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a new column `collect_date` in a table, so that users can specify when they `collected` an object.

Considering that not every user can recall the exact `collect_date`, I would offer them an option to specify year or year/month only, leaving out parts that they can't recall.

Possible queries on `collect_date`:

1. order by `collect_date` desc
2. range, eg. month between 1 and 3

What is a suitable column type for this kind of data in MySQL?

Comment: Why not break the date up into parts (year, month, day)? That way you can always use mysql's date tools and not resort to hacks?

Comment: what operations do u plan to do on it? May be u need to store ranges and not just dates.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I've edited my question and add possible queries.

Comment: How would you do range selects if for some dates months are missing?

Comment: @peterm In that case, I have to ignore them.

Comment: One way is to have a normal date column and flag column that tells wether a date is an exact date or not. For dates where only year was entered add first of January.

Comment: Dates always have a month, day, and year. Always. Without exception. If you're missing any part, you don't have a date, and shouldn't be trying to store it as one.

Comment: @KenWhite Maybe I should use a `varchar`.

Comment: @KenWhite IMHO It's like surrogate keys. You don't have to use them, but it's convenient and fast. Using a date field is convenient and fast.

Comment: You'll have to decide that based on what you need to do with the data specifically. I usually find it best to deal with dates as real dates; if the user can't remember the specific, they should choose an approximate date. "I remember it was in the first part of May, 2013. I think it was the middle of the first week, so I'll use May 4, 2013. It wasn't important enough to track the actual date, so that's close enough." By doing that, you can do actual queries using real date support functions and math.

Comment: @peterm: No, a date field contains a month, day, and year. Read my first comment above. A date **always** consists of a month, day, and year. Always, 100% of the time. If you're missing any part, it is **not** a date.

Comment: @KenWhite That's actually exactly what I proposed. User can enter a date exact or approximate. If user doesn't remember month and a day at all just use predefined values (e.g.) january first. That way you always have a year, a month, and a day. And you can have a flag field that tells that a date entered is exact or not if it's needed at all for app logic.

Comment: @peterm: I was responding specifically to " Using a date field is convenient and fast." which is not what I said at all. I said "Don't use a date if you're not going to store a date." If you're choosing an approximate date, you can still store a date. You cannot store a date that consists of only a month and year, because that's not a date, whether it's convenient or not. It cannot be a date without all three parts: month, day, and year, so if you're not storing all three you shouldn't be considering storing a date (or even thinking about a date), with or without a flag.